# High val_loss and low val_accuracy when training ResNet50 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, training-data, resnet

Ive been training a ResNet50 model with some added layers of my own, however with each epoch comes a higher val_loss and the same val_accuracy. I think its overfitting the model but not sure how i would fix that. Im using FER2013 .jpg dataset to test and train the model.

Code:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(48,48,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
#ResNet model with additional convolutional layers.
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(48,48,3), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_info = model.fit(traindata,epochs=100,validation_data=testdata)


#base_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentrophy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model_info = base_model.fit(traindata, steps_per_epoch=449,epochs=100,validation_data=testdata,validation_steps=112)
```

Im using batch_size of 128, any help would be great.

First epoch results:

```
Epoch 1/100
98/98 [==============================] - 276s 3s/step - loss: 1.6894 - accuracy: 0.3039 - val_loss: 3.2897 - val_accuracy: 0.1737

Epoch 2/100
98/98 [==============================] - 342s 4s/step - loss: 1.4305 - accuracy: 0.3630 - val_loss: 13.5700 - val_accuracy: 0.1737
```

Comment: You only trained for two epochs, why are you even asking us for some behavior that could be just random? You need to train the model to convergence before looking at the loss or predictions.

Comment: Ive trained more than 2 epochs before but forgot to copy the outputs before posting. The same trend occured for 30 epochs with the val_loss reaching around 50.

Comment: It could just be overfitting, which is not something we can fix for you, it is not a programming problem.

Comment: im quite new to using CNNs, i know that overfitting can be an issue but my small brain cant understand why it is happening, what causes it

Answer (score 0):

The output shape of the ResNet model seems to be (2, 2, 2048), so it does not make sense to apply Conv2D layers to it :

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 resnet50 (Functional)       (None, 2, 2, 2048)        23587712  
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 2, 2, 32)          589856    
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 2, 2, 64)          18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 1, 1, 64)         0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1, 1, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 1, 128)         73856     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 1, 1, 128)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 1, 128)         147584    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 1, 1, 128)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 1, 1, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1024)              132096    
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 7175      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 24,556,775
Trainable params: 24,503,655
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

Comment: So are the additional conv layers irrelevant and i should just use the ResNet model by itself?

Comment: You could apply a MaxPooling2D to get a shape=(None, 1, 1, 2048), then a Flatten layer followed by fully connected layers (Dense), or simply a Flatten layer and Dense layers

Comment: After just adding MaxPooling2D and fully connected layers to the model the val_accuracy hovers around 0. and wont go higher, any advice?